# What Operator IS do VB

Tags: vb.net, list, operators

Recently I was trying to Test if 2 Lists are equal and accidentally found the Operator **IS**.

```
If List1 is List2 Then ...
```

But it didn't work (of course my code isn't so simple so anything could go wrong so I don't know if it was the **IS** operator my problem). In any case can anyone tell me what this operator does?

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IS operator is used to compare two object reference variables.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb136x1y.aspx

Comment: Yes I get that but will it work if they just have the same values like

List1.add("1")
List2.add("1")

List1 is List2 = True or False??

Comment: not if List1 and List2 are 2 different objects, in that case it would be false.  the contents of the Lists are irrelevant